# Grok pattern to match URIPATH with optional URIPARAM

Tags: regex, grok, graylog2

I want to use Grok Pattern for filtering out this

```
172.20.20.88 - - [10/Nov/2018:23:49:31 +0700] "GET /id/profile.pl?user=285&device=Bg3tlX HTTP/1.1" 502 852 "-" "Go-http-client/2.0" "0.009"
```

I am using COMMONAPACHELOG

```
%{IPORHOST:clientip} %{HTTPDUSER:ident} %{USER:auth} \[%{HTTPDATE:timestamp}\] "(?:%{WORD:verb} %{NOTSPACE:request}(?: HTTP/%{NUMBER:httpversion})?|%{DATA:rawrequest})" %{NUMBER:response} (?:%{NUMBER:bytes}|-)
```

I have tried `%{URIPATH:request}` and `%{URIPARAM:request}`. The result of request is still `/id/profile.pl?user=285&device=Bg3tlX`. My expectation is `/id/profile.pl`.

My reference is https://github.com/hpcugent/logstash-patterns/blob/master/files/grok-patterns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `%{NOTSPACE:request}` matches any 1 or more non-whitespace chars before `HTTP/1.1" 502 85...` as `NOTSPACE` pattern is `\S+`. So, it matches the whole `/id/profile.pl?user=285&device=Bg3tlX` substring.

You cannot use just `URIPATH` or `URIPARAM`, because you still need to match the rest of the input. You have to use both, but make `URIPARAM` optional after `URIPATH` by enclosing it within an optional non-capturing group, `(?:...)?`.

So, replace `%{NOTSPACE:request}` with

```
%{URIPATH:request}(?:%{URIPARAM:requestparam})?
                  ^^^                        ^^
```

Demo at https://grokdebug.herokuapp.com/:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much... thank you thank you...
I got stuck for 8 hours... almost give up... using regex manually one-by-one crossing in my mind... but you helped me solve it...